# sysssislog table in a user database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis

How can the `sysssislog` table to show up in a user database's system tables?  This is for SQL server 2012.

Comment: The sysssislog table is located in the system database [msdb] under System Tables. Are you asking how can you get the data into a table in a user database?

Comment: Kind of. Actually I see sysssislog table in the user database in the system tables portion of the database in my development environment. I need to do the same in prod envt.

Comment: By default, sysssislog table only exists under System Table for the System databases [msdb]. If you are seeing sysssislog in a user database, then you must have a package that is setup for execution logging and it creates the table in the specified database if it does not exist.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 3):

By default, sysssislog table only exists under System Table for the System databases [msdb]. 
If you are seeing sysssislog in a user database, then you must have a package that is setup for execution logging and it creates the table in the specified database if it does not exist.